# modify text in a <div> using jquery and a callback to mvc3 controler

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a jquery function to get some information from an asp.net mvc 3 controller to my view using a json.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#CraftID").change(function () {
        $.post("/Element/GetItems/", { CraftID: $(this).val(), ElementID: $("#ElementID").val() }, function (data) {
            populateDropdown($("#ItemID"), data);
        });
    });

    $("#ItemID").change(function () {
        $.post("/Element/GetUnit/", { ItemID: $(this).val(), ElementID: $("#ElementID").val() }, function (units) {
            appendUnit($("#factor"), units);
        });
    });

    $("#btn_next").click(function () {
        window.location = "/Element/";
    });

});

function populateDropdown(select, data) {
    select.html('');
    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
        select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.ItemID).html(option.Description));
    });
}  // } inserted here

function appendUnit(factor, units) { };
}  // } removed here
</script>
```

And in razor HTML:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CraftID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Crafts as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "CraftID", "Description"))           
    </div>
            
    <div class="editor-label">
        Leitposition:
    </div>           
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select id="ItemID" name="ItemID"></select> 
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label" id="factor">
        Umrechnungsfaktor:
    </div>
```

My controler looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUnit(int itemid, int elementid)
    {
        try
        {
            Element  element = db.Elements.Single(e => e.ElementID == elementid);
                           
            Item item = db.Items.Single(it => it.ItemID == itemid);

            ItemViewModel ivm = new ItemViewModel(item);

            ElementViewModel evm = new ElementViewModel (element);

            string str_unit = "["+ ivm.Unit_toString() + "/" + evm.Unit_toString() + "]"; 

            return Json(str_unit);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So heres the problem:
When i come on the Site my IDE throws following exeption:

> Laufzeitfehler in Microsoft JScript: Objekt erwartet
>
> Runtimeerror in Microsoft JScript: Object expected

And line: appendUnit($("#factor"), units); is highlighted. I realy don't get what the problem is becouse the debugger finds the correct `<div>`. I know that becouse when i mouseover the function `appendUnit(factor...` it shows me innerHTML: "Umrechnungsfaktor:".

So this was the Problem and now what i am trying to do:
I simply want to render my `<div class="editor-label" id=factor> Umrechnungsfaktor + units </div>`
where units comes from my controler GetUnit.

Function appendUnit(factor, unit) is empty for testing becouse i couldnt find the error it should be something like that:

```
function appendUnit(factor, units) { 
   factor.html = ' ';
   factor.append("Umrechnungsfaktor: " + units.val());
};
```

Comment: Have you verified that the call to `GetUnit` is returning results?

Comment: It would be swell if you could translate the error messages into English for those of us who are less educated ;-)

Comment: 'Objekt erwartet' ..thats an 'Object expected' err

Comment: GetUnit is returning the expected Value, at least thats what i see in the debugger. The strange thing is that I use the same code to populate a dropdownlist first (that works)  and then catch the .change to get some extra information. I hope that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `}` under function `appendUnit () {}` included the func to the function `populatedropdown (select, data) {...}` block. Little mistake, big impact and not easy to track down. I correct it in my post, maybe it is useful for someone ;) thanks